# $_POST не передает данные с формы

Tags: php, ajax, post

### Делаю регистрацию с помощью `ajax и json`.

Но `$_POST['reg-name']` и прочее пустые значения. Но при выводе в console.log(data) при ajax-запросе` данные отображаются.

---

Если раскомментировать условия в файле `signup.php`, то вообще ничего не происходит. Не срабатывает `ajax у словия в success: ...`

---

**include/signup.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/db.php';
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    $_SESSION['logged'] = false;
    $haserror = false;

    if (!$connect) die();

    $name = $_POST['reg-name'];
    $surname = $_POST['reg-surname'];
    $email = $_POST['reg-email'];
    $pass = $_POST['reg-pass'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    file_put_contents( 'debug' . time() . '.log', var_export( print_r($_POST), true));

// Здесь все условия я позначил как комментарии, чтобы посмотреть в чем дело. Оказалось, что переменные с данными о пользователе пустые, по-этому и не срабатывал preg_match();  

        //if (preg_match("/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([a-z0-9_\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/", $email)){
            //if (preg_match("/^[А-ЯІЇ]{1}[А-яії'-]{2,}$/u", $name)){
                //if (preg_match("/^[А-ЯІЇ]{1}[а-яії'-]{2,}$/u", $surname)){
                   // if (preg_match("/([A-z0-9-_']{6,})/i", $pass)){
                       // echo json_encode("success-in");
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = $email";
                        $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                        $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);

                        if ($count == 0){

                            $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`, `name`, `surname`, `date`) VALUES ('$email', '$pass', '$name', '$surname', '$date')";
                            mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                            $_SESSION['user-id'] = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
                            $_SESSION['user-name'] = $name;
                            $_SESSION['user-surname'] = $surname;
                            $_SESSION['user-email'] = $email;
                            $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
                            echo json_encode("success");

                        } else echo json_encode("id-error");

                  //  } else $haserror = true;
               // } else $haserror = true;
            //} else $haserror = true;
       // } else $haserror = true;

        if ($haserror) echo json_encode("value-error");
        mysqli_close();
        exit;
    }
    else {
        include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/error/404.php';
    }
    ?>
```

**Кусочек `index.php`:**

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="place-error"></div>
                <form id="reg-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reg-name" placeholder="Ім'я" pattern="^[А-ЯІЇ]{1}[А-яії'-]{2,}$" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reg-surname" placeholder="Прізвище" pattern="^[А-ЯІЇ]{1}[А-яії'-]{2,}$" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
                            <input name="reg-email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" pattern="^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([a-z0-9_\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,})$" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="register1" type="password" class="form-control" name="reg-pass" placeholder="Пароль" pattern="([A-z0-9-_']{6,})" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="register2" type="password" class="form-control" name="reg-pass-sec" placeholder="Повторіть пароль" pattern="([A-z0-9-_']{6,})" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" required>
                            Я згідний з правилами проекту
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <button id="reg-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Створити профіль</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

**Ну и сам аякс:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        // register
        $('#reg-form').submit(function (e) {
            var isCheck = $('#checkbox1').prop('checked');
            if (isCheck) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = $("#reg-form").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'include/signup.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == "value-error") $('.place-error').html('<p>Ви ввели невірні дані.</p>');
                            else if (data == "id-error") $('.place-error').html('<p>Такий профіль уже існує.</p>');
                                else if (data == "success") location.reload();
                                    else if (data == "success-in"){
                                        console.log("SUCCESS-IN");
                                    }
                        console.log("Nothing was happen 2");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

### В чем ошибка?

Comment: На данный момент ваш signup.php выдает следующее: `"success-in""success""success"true`. Используйте echo json_encode($result) только один раз, в самом конце, а в $result передавайте необходимые значения в зависимости от вашей логики.

Comment: @P.Fateevб да, я заметил это. Но не обратил должного внимания. Ура, заработало!) Дайте полный ответ и я оберу его как верный:) Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле signup.php вы используете `echo json_encode()` в нескольких местах. Поскольку эти места не везде являются взаимоисключающимися, вы можете получить на выходе не совсем то, что ожидаете.

Используйте `echo json_encode($result)` только один раз, в самом конце, а в `$result` передавайте необходимые значения в зависимости от вашей логики.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали метод отправки данных, попробуйте так

```
<form action="" id="reg-form" method="post"></form>
```

Comment: Я указал это в `ajax-запросе`. Попробовал и так.. Нет, не помогло!

Comment: У Вас кнопки не определены, то есть Вы должны кнопке, присвоить имя и с помощью isset проверить была ли нажата кнопка, а после этого получать значения с формы.

Comment: Когда-то делал и без этого, работало и без isset. Но сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код работает, массив post заполняется. $_POST['reg-name'] заполнен, смотрите сами:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/xQmYH/
```

В файле i**nclude/signup.php** присутствует условие `if (!$connect) die();` Проверьте, вы не спутали

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/db.php';
```

с

```
require_once $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/include/db.php';
```

?

Comment: Да нет, не спутал. Смотрю вот, в теге **base** сменил путь к сайту, т.к. писал в PHPStorm'e, на `<head><base href="http://localhost/"></head>`. И начал работать, хоть и не возвращает `json- строки`. Вот посмотрите, кинул на хостинг - http://inbusiness.zzz.com.ua/